# CKEditor Loading Content in Dialog window

Tags: javascript, ajax, ckeditor, yii1.x

I am working on a file manager plugin for `CKEditor & Yii 1`. I have created a button on the editor toolbar and on clicking that button i am opening a dialog window. For loading the content / html of the window i am making an ajax call to my controller action i.e `filemanager/index` which loads the view. Inside that view i have a `javascript` call which initiates the file manager plugin, and populates all the files in the upload directory to the main div with `id="fileview"`, now my problem is that the `javascript` call inside the view is never executed no matter i used `renderPartial('viewname',[],false,true)` inside my index action.

I have the plugin working for `tinyMCE` and currently i am trying to reuse the file manager script to work with CKEditor my file manager script is in `idows-file-browser.min.js` and i call `idowsFileBrowser.init()` to initialize it, but in `tinyMCE` plugin i am using `windowmanager.open()` which is definitely not an ajax call infect it opens a window and load the content returned from the controller action.

I am trying to look for a way that i do not have to change anything for the existing plugin script file or the views, but it seems like that for `CKEditor` i might need to move the `idowsFileBrowser.init()` call inside the `idowsfilemanagerdialog.js` file after receiving the response from the ajax call.

Can anyone help me out to make it work without changing the flow.

***idowsfilemanagerdialog.js***

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('idowsfilemanagerDialog', function(editor) {
    return {
        title: 'Tinyii Filemanager By IDOWS',
        minWidth: 850,
        minHeight: 600,
        contents: [{
            id: "File list",
            elements: [{
                type: 'html',
                id: 'foo',
                html: '<div id="main-container"></div>',
            }]
        }],
        onLoad: function() {
            var document = this.getElement().getDocument();
            var element = document.getById('main-container');

            $.ajax({
                url: '/filemanager/index',
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    editor: '_CK'
                }
            }).done(function(res) {
                if (element) {
                    element.setHtml(res);
                }
            });

        },
    };
});
```

***index action inside the FilemanagerController***

```
/**
     * Index main Entry Action for filemanager
     * Opens Main modal window for the file manager
     */
    public function actionIndex() {
        $model = new TinyiiAssetUploadForm();
        $uploadDir = str_replace ( "\\" , "/" , Yii::app ()->basePath . '/..' . Yii::app ()->params['UPLOAD_DIR'] );
        $uploadDirExists = is_dir ( realpath ( $uploadDir ) );

        if ( !$uploadDirExists ) {
            throw new Exception ( 'The upload directory you specified in your param file does not exist.' . $uploadDir );
        }
        $this->renderPartial ( 'dialog' , array( 'model' => $model ) , false , true );
    }
```

***View file***

```
    $cs->registerScriptFile ( Yii::app ()->params['PLUGIN_DIR'.$this->editorType] . '/js/idows-file-browser.min.js' );
    $cs->registerScript ( 'loadtree' , 'idowsFileBrowser.init();',CClientScript::POS_LOAD );
    ?>
    <?php echo $this->renderPartial ( 'alerts' ); ?>
    <div class="idows-container-body">

        <div class="idows-abs-end"></div>
        <div class="idows-container idows-first idows-last" >
            <div class="idows-container-body " style="width:100%;">

                <div class="idows-abs-end"></div>
                <div class="idows-container idows-first" style="border-width: 0px 0px 1px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 38px;">

                    <!--UPLOAD PROGRESS INFO BAR-->
                    <div id="upload_in_progress" class="upload_infobar">
                        <img src="<?= Yii::app ()->params['PLUGIN_DIR'.$this->editorType] ?>/skin/img/loader.gif" width="16" height="16" class="spinner">
                        Upload in progress&hellip; 
                        <div id="upload_additional_info"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="upload_infobar" class="upload_infobar"></div>

                    <!--CONTROLS CONTAINER-->
                    <div class="idows-container-body idows-menubar idows-panel" style="width: 100%;">
                        <div class="idows-abs-end"></div>
                        <?php echo $this->renderPartial ( 'controls' , [ 'model' => $model ] ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- FILE BROWSER  -->
                    <div class="idows-container idows-float-panel idows-last" role="group" style="position: relative;">
                        <div class="idows-thumbnailview" id="file_container">
    <div class="idows-container-body idows-flow-layout" id="fileview">
    </div>
</div>
                    </div>
                    <?= CHtml::hiddenField ( 'current_template' , 'thumbview' , [ 'id' => 'current_template' ] ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- IFRAME FOR FILE UPLOAD -->
    <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="<?= Yii::app ()->getBaseUrl ( true ) ?>/index.php?r=filemanager/blank"></iframe>

    <!-- THICK BOX CONTAINER AND MASK -->
    <div id="dialog" class="window">
        <a href="#." class="close-preview"/>x</a>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <?=
    $this->renderPartial ( 'bootstrap-modals' )?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i had to follow the same modal window structure as `tinyMCE` is following that means creating an iframe and pointing it to the the action `/filemanager/index` and all worked like a charm, the ajax call wont run and load content for the inline javascript inside the view file, here is the code for my dialog's  `onLoad` anyone else is trying to do the same.

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('idowsfilemanagerDialog', function(editor) {
    return {
        title: 'Tinyii Filemanager By IDOWS',
        minWidth: 850,
        minHeight: 650,
        buttons: false,
        contents: [{
            id: "File list",
            elements: [{
                type: 'html',
                id: 'foo',
                html: '<div id="main-container"></div>',
            }]
        }],
        onLoad: function() {
            let document = this.getElement().getDocument();
            $('<iframe>', {
                id: 'file-manager-frame',
                src: '/filemanager/index?editor=_CK',
                frameborder: 0,
                width: this.definition.dialog.definition.minWidth,
                height: this.definition.dialog.definition.minHeight,
            }).appendTo("#main-container");
        },
    };
});
```